# Error NFS server start

Tags: runtime-error, startup, nfs

I try to start nfs server, but I have this problem. Any idea? Thanks

OS: Debian 8 Jessie

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Reproduce your problem and run `journalctl -xn` to see what is really happening, though you are not using the Linux under rpm, I suggest you to ask for further help at debian`s bug tracking system: https://www.debian.org/Bugs/